# html страница работает не корректно(пропадает разметка) вероятно из-за обновления с 10й до 11й windows

Tags: html, css, html5, windows-11

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вероятно после обновления с 10 windows до 11 вводя код в sublime text или любых других компиляторах он перестал учитывать саму разметку при открытии файла в браузере выдаёт лишь текст кнопки и ссылки на них и тому подобное прикреплю скриншот вывода, то что должно вывестись и код для него. Как я могу исправить
данную проблему и сделать чтоб разметка в коде тоже учитывалась и выводила корректный результат, а не только текст, картинки и кнопки
css файл не требуется в данном промежутке кода до обновления у меня всё работало
[image: вывод]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Метка первого слайда</h5>
        <p>Некоторый репрезентативный заполнитель для первого слайда.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Метка второго слайда</h5>
        <p>Некоторый репрезентативный заполнитель для второго слайда.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Метка третьего слайда</h5>
        <p>Некоторый репрезентативный заполнитель для третьего слайда.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"  data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Предыдущий</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions"  data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Следующий</span>
  </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А где у вас подключается css?

Comment: С каких это пор Sublime Text является компилятором? Код в браузере выглядит +/- так же как и в воспроизводимом примере который Вы привели. Наверное речь о том, что игнорируются некие стили, но я не вижу их подключения в примере. Какой вид должна иметь страница и прочие детали не помешали бы.

Comment: Для того чтобы это работало, как минимум нужно подключить CSS и JS файлы, самого Bootstrap. Так уж получилось, что без этих файлов разметка в необходимом Вам виде отображаться не будет (либо же Вы работаете с исходниками Bootstrap, но в любом случае это требует подключения некоего CSS и JS файла). Каким образом это работало без подключения CSS и JS ранее и почему, известно только Вам. Может Вы раньше запускали какую-то сборку или предпринимали какие-то дополнительные действия?

Comment: да всё так как вы и сказали спасибо за помощь